# Turn a List into a Data frame PYTHON - SQL

Tags: python, sql-server, pandas, dataframe

I am currently pulling some data from SQL Server via python,

Using the below:

```
import pyodbc
data = []
con = pyodbc.connect('Trusted_Connection=yes', driver = '{SQL Server}',server = 'bhxsql2014-dev', database = 'BMAnalytics')

cursor = con.cursor()

cursor.execute(" select * from dbo.EUActiveStores ")
for columns in cursor.fetchall():
    data.append(columns[0:])

print(data)
```

It returns data in the following format (Top 2 rows as sample):

```
[(1.0, 'Bradford', 'Main', 1.0, 'UK', 850.3489216, 79.0, 'Sharon Watson', 'Malcolm Bateman', 0.0, '199446', 199602.0, 'ST1', 1201.0, '12', 53.794851, -1.755584, 'COMP', 'Main', 'MALL', None), (4.0, 'EASTBOURNE', 'Main', 1.0, 'UK', 646.9788276755199, 60.10629999999999, 'Jocelyn Hill', 'Andrea Varley', 0.0, '199642', 199750.0, 'ST1', 1304.0, '13', 50.7696, 0.2859, 'COMP', 'Main', 'MALL', None),
```

Seems each Row is contained within parenthesis, and separated by a comma.

I have no idea how to turn this into a data frame, any advice ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [Pandas.read_sql()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_sql.html) method - it will take care of the rest:

```
df = pd.read_sql(query, con)
```

You may also want to use very fast module [turbodbc](http://turbodbc.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pages/introduction.html):

```
from turbodbc import connect, make_options
options = make_options()
connection = connect(dsn="my_dsn", turbodbc_options=options)

cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.execute("SELECT A, B FROM my_table")
df = cursor.fetchallarrow(strings_as_dictionary=True).to_pandas()
cursor.close()
```

Comment: WOW, that was a whole lot simpler than i thought it would be

Comment: @User91504, yeah, Pandas is amazing! :)

Comment: I agree, maxu ;)

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative would be to use [Pandas.DataFrame.from_records()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.from_records.html) method. But, I would only do this if you need to do any non-pandas processing of the query results before building the dataframe. Otherwise, @MaxU has the better answer.

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(data, columns=['list','of','columns'])
```